# install SceneEventFilter on QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, events, qgraphicsitem

I'm working on a Qt Widget App in MAX OS X, where i have QGraphicsView and a set of movable  QGraphicsEllipseItem drawn on it.

I'm also using an event filter to filter events from my class && react to them.

Now, I've been using eventfilter on my `QGraphicsView` and tried getting events when the `EllipseItems` changed posisions, but that didn't work.

So I think I need to install event Filters on the `QGraphicsItems` themselves, but they only support `sceneEventFilter`.

So my question is **how to set it up so that my class can listen to events generated by the registered QGraphicsItems**?

*I need to listen in that class because i need to trigger recalcultion of parameters in the class when the points change position.*

example:

```
 Wiget App
 ---------
   -ui - contains QGraphicsView
   -codebehind - sets up the QGraphicsView, 
               - creates the points and adds them to the scene of the view
               - also should have the event filter method implementation to listen to
                 changes of the items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I am not really answering how to set up any event filtering in the `QGraphicsItems` but you can get events from the `QGraphicsScene` associated with a `QGraphicsView`.

Below is an example how to catch the signal `changed(...)` of the scene and display information about which item was moved.

This way is certainly not optimized but might give you an idea on how to handle events. Also, I am using the toolTip to set and retrieve a string on the item which obviously is a ridiculous thing to do but should just illustrate that I am getting the item back and can interact with it.

Let me know if this is of any help, as said at the beginning, I am answering along somewhat different lines than what you asked.

**MyGraphicsView.h**

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>


class MyGraphicsView: public QGraphicsView
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MyGraphicsView() {}
  MyGraphicsView( QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MyGraphicsView() {};

public slots:
  void itemWasMoved( const QList<QRectF> & region );
private:
  QGraphicsEllipseItem *item;
};
```

**MyGraphicsView.cpp**

```
#include "MyGraphicsView.h"
#include <QtCore>

MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView( QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(scene,parent)
{
  item = new QGraphicsEllipseItem( 0, this->scene() );
  item->setRect( -50.0, -50.0, 100.0, 100.0 );
  item->setFlag( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable );
  item->setToolTip(tr("My Ellipse"));
  connect(this->scene(), SIGNAL(changed( const QList<QRectF> & ) ), this, SLOT( itemWasMoved( const QList<QRectF> & ) ) );
}

void MyGraphicsView::itemWasMoved( const QList<QRectF> & region )
{
  for( int i = 0; i < region.count(); ++i ) {
    const QRectF &rect = region.at(i);
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *item = dynamic_cast<QGraphicsEllipseItem*>(this->items(mapFromScene(rect)).at(0) );
    if( item ) {
      qDebug() << item->toolTip();
    }
  }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MyGraphicsView.h"
#include <QApplication>


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QGraphicsScene scene;
  scene.setSceneRect( -100.0, -100.0, 200.0, 200.0 );

  MyGraphicsView view( &scene );
  view.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: And yes, it's very helpful because it essentially allows me to do what i need to do :)